# Access public available Amazon S3 file from Apache Spark

Tags: scala, amazon-s3, apache-spark

I have a public available Amazon s3 resource (text file) and want to access it from spark. That means - I don't have any Amazon credentials - it works fine if I want to just download it:

```
val bucket = "<my-bucket>"
val key = "<my-key>"

val client = new AmazonS3Client
val o = client.getObject(bucket, key)
val content = o.getObjectContent // <= can be read and used as input stream
```

However, when I try to access the same resource from spark context

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("app").setMaster("local")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val f = sc.textFile(s"s3a://$bucket/$key")
println(f.count())
```

I receive the following error with stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain
    at com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentialsProviderChain.getCredentials(AWSCredentialsProviderChain.java:117)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:3521)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.headBucket(AmazonS3Client.java:1031)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.doesBucketExist(AmazonS3Client.java:994)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.initialize(S3AFileSystem.java:297)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2653)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:92)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2687)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2669)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:371)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:295)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:270)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:207)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:219)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:217)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:217)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:32)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:219)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:217)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:217)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1781)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.count(RDD.scala:1099)
    at com.example.Main$.main(Main.scala:14)
    at com.example.Main.main(Main.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
```

I don't want to provide any AWS credentials - I just want to access resource anonymously (for now) - how to achieve this? I probably need to make it use something like AnonymousAWSCredentialsProvider - but how to put it inside spark or hadoop?

P.S. My build.sbt just in case

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.4.1",
  "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-aws" % "2.7.1"
)
```

UPDATED: After I did some investigations - I see the reason why itsn't working.

First of all, S3AFileSystem creates AWS client with the following order of credentials:

```
AWSCredentialsProviderChain credentials = new AWSCredentialsProviderChain(
    new BasicAWSCredentialsProvider(accessKey, secretKey),
    new InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider(),
    new AnonymousAWSCredentialsProvider()
);
```

"accessKey" and "secretKey" values are taken from the spark conf instance (keys must be "fs.s3a.access.key" and "fs.s3a.secret.key" or org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.Constants.ACCESS_KEY and org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.Constants.SECRET_KEY constants, which is more convenient).

Second - you probably see that AnonymousAWSCredentialsProvider is the third option (last priority) - what could possible be wrong with that? See the implementation of AnonymousAWSCredentials:

```
public class AnonymousAWSCredentials implements AWSCredentials {

    public String getAWSAccessKeyId() {
        return null;
    }

    public String getAWSSecretKey() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

It simply returns null for both access key and secret key. Sounds reasonable. But look inside AWSCredentialsProviderChain:

```
AWSCredentials credentials = provider.getCredentials();

if (credentials.getAWSAccessKeyId() != null &&
    credentials.getAWSSecretKey() != null) {
    log.debug("Loading credentials from " + provider.toString());

    lastUsedProvider = provider;
    return credentials;
}
```

It doesn't choose provider in case both keys are null - that means anonymous credentials can't work. Looks like a bug inside aws-java-sdk-1.7.4. I tried to use latest version - but it's incompatible with hadoop-aws-2.7.1.

Any other ideas?

Comment: have you had any success, maybe with more recent versions ?

Comment: no, I didn't try this for a while - I even forgot about it, don't use amazon s3 for anything

Answer (score 5):

This is what helped me:

```
val session = SparkSession.builder()
  .appName("App")
  .master("local[*]") 
  .config("fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.AnonymousAWSCredentialsProvider")
  .getOrCreate()

val df = session.read.csv(filesFromS3:_*)
```

Versions:

```
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.4.0",
"org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-aws" % "2.8.5",
```

Documentation:
https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/index.html#Authentication_properties

Comment: If this configuration fails for you note that it requires hadoop-aws 2.8.0 or greater (see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-13237)

Answer (score 3):

I personally never accessed public data from Spark. You can try to use dummy credentials, or to create ones just for this usage. Set them directly on the SparkConf object.

```
val sparkConf: SparkConf = ???
val accessKeyId: String = ???
val secretAccessKey: String = ???
sparkConf.set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3.awsAccessKeyId", accessKeyId)
sparkConf.set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId", accessKeyId)
sparkConf.set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3.awsSecretAccessKey", secretAccessKey)
sparkConf.set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey", secretAccessKey)
```

As an alternative, read the documentation of `DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain` to see where the credentials are looked for. The list (order is important) is:

> - Environment Variables - AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_KEY
> - Java System Properties - aws.accessKeyId and aws.secretKey
> - Credential profiles file at the default location (~/.aws/credentials) shared by all AWS SDKs and the AWS CLI
> - Instance profile credentials delivered through the Amazon EC2 metadata service

Comment: Something is still wrong. I added the following values to the keys you gave me (exact string "aaa" as dummy credentials). I expected to see auth error in worst case, but I see the same exception "Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain"

Comment: The correct keys must be "spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key" and "spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.secret.key'. By the way, providing dummy values didn't help - now I see 403 error. Looks like it's impossible to use anonymous credentials for AWS S3 with spark.

And according to the source code - the order of credentials is different.
    AWSCredentialsProviderChain credentials = new AWSCredentialsProviderChain(
        new BasicAWSCredentialsProvider(accessKey, secretKey),
        new InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider(),
        new AnonymousAWSCredentialsProvider()
    );

And anonymous simply doesn't work.

Comment: Ok, sorry I didn't see you were using the `s3a` protocol. Did you try with the `s3n` one?

Answer (score 3):

It seems you can now use the aws.credentials.provider config key to use anonymous access given by org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.AnonymousAWSCredentialsProvider, which correctly [special case](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/2b2399d623539ab68e71a38fa9fbfc9a405bddb8/hadoop-tools/hadoop-aws/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/fs/s3a/AWSCredentialProviderList.java#L120) the anonymous provider. However, you need a newer hadoop-aws than 2.7, which means you also need a spark installation without a bundled hadoop.

Here is how I did it colab:

```
!apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk-headless -qq > /dev/null
!wget -q http://apache.osuosl.org/spark/spark-2.3.1/spark-2.3.1-bin-without-hadoop.tgz
!tar xf spark-2.3.1-bin-without-hadoop.tgz
!pip install -q findspark
!pip install -q pyarrow
```

Now we install hadoop on the side, and set the output of `hadoop classpath` to `SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH`, so spark can see it.

```
import os
!wget -q http://mirror.nbtelecom.com.br/apache/hadoop/common/hadoop-2.8.4/hadoop-2.8.4.tar.gz
!tar xf hadoop-2.8.4.tar.gz
os.environ['HADOOP_HOME']= '/content/hadoop-2.8.4'
os.environ["SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH"] = "/content/hadoop-2.8.4/etc/hadoop:/content/hadoop-2.8.4/share/hadoop/common/lib/*:/content/hadoop-2.8.4/share/hadoop/common/*:/content/hadoop-2.8.4/share/hadoop/hdfs:/content/hadoop-2.8.4/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*:/content/hadoop-2.8.4/share/hadoop/hdfs/*:/content/hadoop-2.8.4/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/*:/content/hadoop-2.8.4/share/hadoop/yarn/*:/content/hadoop-2.8.4/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/*:/content/hadoop-2.8.4/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*:/content/hadoop-2.8.4/contrib/capacity-scheduler/*.jar"
```

Then we do like in https://mikestaszel.com/2018/03/07/apache-spark-on-google-colaboratory/, but add s3a and anonymous reading support, which is what the question is about.

```
import os
os.environ["JAVA_HOME"] = "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64"
os.environ["SPARK_HOME"] = "/content/spark-2.3.1-bin-without-hadoop"
os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--packages com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.10.6,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.8.4 --conf spark.sql.execution.arrow.enabled=true --conf spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider=org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.AnonymousAWSCredentialsProvider pyspark-shell'
```

And finally we can create the session.

```
import findspark
findspark.init()
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
```

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR for `pyspark`:

```bash
pyspark \
  --packages org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:3.3.2 \
  --conf spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider=org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.AnonymousAWSCredentialsProvider

>>> spark.read.csv('s3a://landsat-pds/scene_list.gz').show()
```

(Tested with Apache Spark 3.3.2.)